# Reactjs submit button disable issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submit, form-submit, disable

Guys I am facing issue with **submit button disable** function

I have set 3 conditions:

1. Password shall be greater than 8 characters
2. Should contain at least 1 number
3. Client shall click on terms and privacy

And only if these 3 conditions satisfied will the boolean "allvalid" be set as true

Issues:
I discovered that after I fulfilled all the conditions the button is still disabled
But when I put 1 more character in the password submit button works, and I delete that 1 character which is still working(now 8 chars), but when I delete one more(now 7) submit button is still enabled, only when I reduce to 6 it's disabled again

I want it to be enabled exactly when all the conditions are fulfilled and disabled immediately when it's not

Here's the code

```
export function SignupForm(props) {
  const { switchToSignin } = useContext(AccountContext);
  const [passwordOne, setPasswordOne] = useState("")

  // booleans for password validations
  const [containsN, setContainsN] = useState(false) // number
  const [contains8C, setContains8C] = useState(false) // min 8 characters

  // checks all validations are true
  const [allValid, setAllValid] = useState(false)
  const [terms,setTerms]=useState(false)
  // Client shall check on the terms otherwise submit button is disabled
  const checkTerms=() => {
    setTerms(true)
  }
  const validatePassword = () => {
    // has number
    if (/\d/.test(passwordOne)) setContainsN(true)
    else setContainsN(false)

    // has 8 characters
    if (passwordOne.length >= 8) setContains8C(true)
    else setContains8C(false)

     // all validations passed
    if (containsN  && contains8C && terms) setAllValid(true)
    else setAllValid(false)
  }

  const handleSubmit=(e)=> {
    alert('Submitted' );
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <BoxContainer>
        <FormContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
          <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <Input type="password" placeholder="Password"
          value={passwordOne} 
                          onChange={e=>setPasswordOne(e.target.value)} 
                          onKeyUp={validatePassword}
          />
          <column>
            <Condition>
              <img className="check" src={contains8C?check:uncheck}  alt="icon1" />
                8 Characters min.
              <img className="check" src={containsN?check:uncheck}  alt="icon2" />
              One number
            </Condition>
          </column>
          <column>
            <Checkbox>
              <input type="checkbox" onClick={checkTerms}></input>
            </Checkbox>
            <Terms align='left'>By creating account, you agree to accept our Privacy policy, Terms of Service and Notification settings.</Terms>
          </column>
          
          <Marginer direction="vertical" margin={10} />  
          <SubmitButton type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!allValid}>Signup</SubmitButton>
        </FormContainer>)
```

Comment: Do you have public github repo to reproduce issue ?

Comment: Thanks for your kind gesture in advance, kindly find the following link https://github.com/BunanSia/React_register_login/blob/master/src/components/accountBox/signupForm.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your repository and I think I found the issue.

First thing your SubmitButton component disable property is not working correctly.

So that's why I changed it to basic HTML button to make sure value handled normally.

So new like of button should looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!allValid}>Signup</button>
```

Another point about checkbox. You need to handle is it checked or not, so new checkbox button should looks this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick={(e)=>checkTerms(e)}></input>
```

And final step you need to track validation values at form and you should update the state again to make button disabled and enabled. For this purpose, you need to use useEffect hook like this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    // Track all local states and validate the term
    validatePassword()
 },[passwordOne,terms,containsN,contains8C,validatePassword]);
```

and new checkTerms function will be:

```
const checkTerms=(e) => {
   setTerms(e.target.checked)
}
```

I will put final signupForm.jsx for you:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { useContext } from "react";
import {
  BoldLink,
  BoxContainer,
  FormContainer,
  Input,
  MutedLink
} from "./common";
import { Marginer } from "../marginer";
import { AccountContext } from "./accountContext";
import styled from "styled-components";
import check from "./images/check.png";
import uncheck from "./images/uncheck.png";

const Terms = styled.h5`
  width: 250px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 7px;
`;

const Condition= styled.div`
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  flex:50%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 2px;
`;

const Checkbox= styled.div`
  background: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  flex:50%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 2px;
`;


export function SignupForm(props) {
  const { switchToSignin } = useContext(AccountContext);
  const [passwordOne, setPasswordOne] = useState("")

  // booleans for password validations
  const [containsN, setContainsN] = useState(false) // number
  const [contains8C, setContains8C] = useState(false) // min 8 characters

  // checks all validations are true
  const [allValid, setAllValid] = useState(false)
  const [terms,setTerms]=useState(false)
  // labels and state boolean corresponding to each validation
  const checkTerms=(e) => {
    setTerms(e.target.checked)
  }

  const validatePassword = () => {
    // has number
    if (/\d/.test(passwordOne)) setContainsN(true)
    else setContainsN(false)

    // has 8 characters
    if (passwordOne.length >= 8) setContains8C(true)
    else setContains8C(false)

     // all validations passed
    if (containsN  && contains8C && terms) setAllValid(true)
    else setAllValid(false)
  }

  const handleSubmit=(e)=> {
    alert('Submitted' );
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    // Track all local states and validate the term
    validatePassword()
  },[passwordOne,terms,containsN,contains8C,validatePassword]);

  return (
    <BoxContainer>
        <FormContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" />
          <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          <Input type="password" placeholder="Password"
          value={passwordOne}
                          onChange={e=>setPasswordOne(e.target.value)}
                          onKeyUp={validatePassword}
          />
          <column>
            <Condition>
              <img className="check" src={contains8C?check:uncheck}  alt="icon1" />
                8 Characters min.
              <img className="check" src={containsN?check:uncheck}  alt="icon2" />
              One number
            </Condition>
          </column>
          <column>
            <Checkbox>
              <input type="checkbox" onClick={(e)=>checkTerms(e)}></input>
            </Checkbox>
            <Terms align='left'>By creating account, you agree to accept our Privacy policy, Terms of Service and Notification settings.</Terms>
          </column>

          <Marginer direction="vertical" margin={10} />
          <button type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={!allValid}>Signup</button>
        </FormContainer>
      <Marginer direction="vertical" margin="1em" />
      <MutedLink href="#">
        Already have an account?
        <BoldLink href="#" onClick={switchToSignin}>
          Signin
        </BoldLink>
      </MutedLink>
    </BoxContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to express my gratitude, I should improve my basis knowledge as a developer, thank you and wish you all the best for your career

Comment: Commit being added and credit is given to you guys shorturl.at/gxyL9

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the asynchronous behaviour of hooks in react.Check the value of allvalid state, as it is depending on other states.Make sure allvalid state is updated correctly after updation of state on which it is dependent.

Comment: Hi Shrinidhi bhai I am very grateful for your comment, I'd like to upvote your answer but due to lack of reputation I couldn't as of now. Once I get enough point I would certainly do it

Comment: I have checked the allvalid value and you are right, it has not been updated correctly. I would dig into the asynchronous behaviour of hooks in react and try to find a solution

Comment: welcome, try to use useEffect hook and there you update allvalid state and pass the other state  on which allvalid state is dependent as dependency array in useEffect hook.